# How to get the selected model for a given row onChange with Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

I have a custom Ember.Select that I'm overriding the "change" event to handle the event myself (to fire off an xhr for example)

In my handlebars file, I add a select to each row (ArrayController backed)

```
{{#each thing in controller}}
{{view App.CustomSelect value=thing.category content=configuration optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
{{/each}}
```

In my javascript I handle the event like so

```
App.CustomSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
  change: function(x) {
    //in here I can only get the selected option / value
    //what I really need is both that value (above)
    //and the model for this given row
  }
});
```

How can I get the model bound to that specific select in the change event?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through my own code, to get the model you need to do the following:

```
App.CustomSelect = Ember.Select.extend({
  change: function(x) {
    var selectedModel = this.get('selection');
  }
});
```

Comment: when my controller for the template is an ArrayController this "selection" is the option -not the outter model itself